# How to put UILabel.textColor in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to put the font to my UILabel, i do it like this : `myLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0/255 green:239.0/255 blue:236.0/255 alpha:1.0f];` My question is : how i can do exactly the same think with Interface Builder ? i know that i will use the inspector color in IB, but i don't know how to put the same think, for example how to put : `red:242.0/255` in  IB, and the alpha :`1.0f` ? thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place a label in IB,

go to Attribute Inspector -> Text Color-> Other

In colors window, Go to Color Sliders (2nd tab on top)
Click on Grey Scale Slider and change it to RGB Sliders.

There you can put R/G/B values as you have done in code.
You dont need to put like: x/255
just set Red as : 242
Alpha can be set between 0 - 1 with Opacity slider at the bottom 0 - 100.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but if i put for example in IB : red :242 green:239 blue:236 and the opacité 100%, it gives not me the same think with [UIColor colorWith....]; thanks

Comment: it has to and it does give the same color - otherwise what is the use of providing RGB values input feature?